FedCM and One Tap: Clicking on X button doesn't stop automatic logging in
With the new FedCM One Tap clicking on X button doesn't not stop automatic sign-in.
From the docs:
"For accessibility consideration, an ID token is shared with your website"
However, it still calls the callback method provided to google.accounts.id.initialize.
In the One Tap before FedCM with automatic log in when I clicked "Cancel" button the callback was not invoked and automatic popup was changed to popup with "Continue as ..." button
With FedCM automatic log in when I click on "x" popup disappears but callback function is still invoked and I am still being logged in.
The same thing is happening with non-automatic one tap popup with FedCm. Click on "Continue as ..." and then click on "X" button. It will still log in.
Is there any way that I can cancel users being logged in after clicking X button?
Here is how I initialize One Tap:
window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
    auto_select: true,
    callback: googleOneTapCallback,
    cancel_on_tap_outside: false,
    client_id: googleId,
    itp_support: false,
    use_fedcm_for_prompt: true, // however we are switched to FedCM even without this boolean
    log_level: 'debug', // just for local development
});

plus this is for debugging:
window.google.accounts.id.prompt((notification) => console.log('notification', notification)); 
Now when I have an automatic sign-in flow and click on X:

prompt disappears
I am still being logged
I have in console

{
    "g": "dismissed",
    "i": "credential_returned"
}

The exact same object is passed even if I don't click on X button and allow automatic sign-in to progress (so I couldn't find a way to differentiate that)
When I have sign in with "Continue as..." button and I just close it by clicking on X:

prompt disappears
I am not logged in
I have in console:

{
    "g": "skipped",
    "l": "unknown_reason"
}
User declined or dismissed prompt. API exponential cool down triggered.

I know about google.accounts.id.cancel() method however I don't know how to grab X button in the new FedCM popup.

With FedCM, users can't cancel automatic sign in to address the accessibility concerns. The X on the One Tap during automatic sign in is to close the One Tap prompt before it closes itself, but it doesn't stop the sign in process.
